# Translating PHPs "setrawcookie()" to .NET

Tags: php, .net, cookies

I need to translate the following PHP script to .NET, but can't find any documentation on a C#/ASP.NET equivalent for setrawcookie():

```
<?php
    $type = $_REQUEST['type'];
    $location = "Location: /includes/fonts/universltstd-lightultracn-webfont.".$type;

    // create a cookie
    setrawcookie("FontDownloaded", 1, time()+3600*24, '/');
    header($location);

?>
```

Comment: "Translating PHP script to .NET" isn't really as simple as a line-by-line translation, FYI

Comment: In this case `setrawcookie` is exactly the same as `setcookie`

Comment: Doesn't look like you need `setrawcookie`. `setcookie` would work fine for setting a value of `1`.

Comment: What language .. and/or framework. VB.Net vs C# vs F# and ASP.Net WebForms vs ASP.Net MVC

Answer (score 0):

```
Response.Cookies["FontDownloaded"].Value = 1;
Response.Cookies["FontDownloaded"].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a peek at [This page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/78c837bd.aspx)

If you want to use the default ASP.NET Cookie

```
Response.Cookies["UserSettings"]["Font"] = "Arial";
Response.Cookies["UserSettings"]["Color"] = "Blue";
Response.Cookies["UserSettings"].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1d);
```

If you want to set a new cookie

```
HttpCookie myCookie = new HttpCookie("UserSettings");
myCookie["Font"] = "Arial";
myCookie["Color"] = "Blue";
myCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1d);
Response.Cookies.Add(myCookie);
```